# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied Python subprocess.call()

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a subprocess in python but I get error message:
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

```
cp2 = cp2.lstrip("~")
cp2 = wilixdirectory+"/Users/"+loggedusr+cp2 
    if cp3 == None:
    subprocess.call([cp2])
else:
    subprocess.call([cp2, cp3])
```

cp2 and cp3 are user inputs for directories

wilixdirectory is a directory

loggedusr is a string like "Bob" or "Joe"

The code is running out of Unix

Comment: Can you *show* your code? And what environment is this running in, with what permissions?

Comment: Check the value of `cp2`. Is it what you expect? Is it missing a leading slash, or does it have one where none was supposed to be? If it names a real file, do you have permission to access the file?

Comment: you could use `cp2 = os.path.expanduser(cp2)` instead of `cp2.lstrip("~"); cp2 = wilixdirectory+"/Users/"+loggedusr+cp2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assuming the path starts with a slash, and concatenating using `+`, use `os.path.join()` to create the path:

```
import os.path

basepath = os.path.join(wilixdirectory, 'Users', loggedusr)
cp2 = cp2.lstrip('~/')
cp2 = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, cp2))
if not cp2.startswith(basepath + os.path.pathsep):
    # something is wrong still, the absolute final path is not inside of
    # user directory, bail now.
    raise ValueError('Not a valid command')

# Perhaps test if os.path.isfile(cp2) is True?

args = [cp2]
if cp3 is not None:
    args.append[cp3]

subprocess.call(args)
```

Note that I strip `~`, and `/` from the start of `cp2` to remove any accidental start characters from the user input, then use `os.path.abspath()` to make sure the path is a canonical path, with any `./` and `../` entries resolved. You *do* then need to verify that the final result is still within the users' directory and not outside of it.

You could test with `os.path.isfile()` to see if the `cp2` path actually points to an actual file before running `subprocess.call()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

That would work for Linux but for Unix:

```
subprocess.call(["open","-a",cp2])
```

for Windows:

```
subprocess.call(["start",cp2])
```

Comment: you could also check whether `webbrowser.open(cp2)` does the right thing in your case.