# Open python file from other python file using subprocess, permission denied error

Tags: python, audio

I have a Python file that is capable of playing wav files,
 and there is another Python file which detects the Flame using external Flame Sensor,

What I wanted to do is, if flame is detected play the `Play.py` file

So after exploring i have found this,

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("./play.py", shell=True)
```

I tried to execute it by pasting it in an empty file and named it `Test.py`

But I am getting this error,

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./play.py: Permission denied
```

Both `play.py` and `Test.py` are in the same directory.

on the other hand, I am able to play `play.py` file separately

```
python play.py
```

But i am getting the error when i am running it from the other python file using subprocess.
Does any body know the reason ?

and yes, I am executing it as root.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/18941619/158111 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the file as `./play.py`, you need to provide execution permissions to this file first.

```
chmod +x play.py
```

And add `#!/usr/bin/python` to the top of this file.

Otherwise, you can also run it as:

```
import sys
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'play.py'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you just import the play.py file is not clear to me. If it's all python shouldn't it make it easy for you?
However:
You gave yourself the answer:

```
subprocess.call("python play.py", shell=True)
```